# Python - sorting a list

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-3.x

I just started playing with a list and would like to know.

If I have a data in a list in a format `['John 1', 'Jack 2']`

How to sort them by the number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can pass a `key` to the `sorted` function](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) which extracts the number by splitting on the space and then converts it to an integer.

```
a = ['John 2', 'Jack 1']

print(sorted(a, key=lambda x:int(x.split(' ')[-1])))
# ['Jack 1', 'John 2']
```

Comment: Can you please show me how to sort list in a opposite way?         mylist =['Jack 1', 'John 2']                                           and i want to get ['John 2', 'Jack 1']

Comment: @Zelenypan you can instead use the `reversed` function to sort something in the "opposite" direction. Or you can pass `reverse=True` to `a.sort(reverse=True)`.

Answer (score 0):

[`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort), [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) accept optional `key` parameter. The return value of the function will be used as comparison key.

```
>>> sorted(['John 1', 'Jedi 3', 'Jack 2'], key=lambda x: int(x.split()[-1]))
['John 1', 'Jack 2', 'Jedi 3']
```